# How can I request for an extension of my summer job if the company do not mention their interest?

Tags: contract-extension

I am about to complete my summer job by the end of this week. But I could say that I worked really well and everyone seemed to appreciate it. I have not expressed that I would want an extension yet (In short, we all need jobs and cannot afford unemployement). But I was planning to talk to the manager about it in a decent and positive way that even if their answer is negative I would stay positive. But she knows that this is my last week and she has not asked me that if I want a continuation. Which to me is an assumption that they do not want me anymore? Should I still express it that if I can have an extension? If yes then how can I put up a request?

On a personal level, the depression of unemployment 'again' is quite unbearable but I am still trying to stay positive and professional and looking for more opportunities.

Comment: "that this is my last" ... what day at work? could you clarify that?

Comment: This is my last week! Sorry for the missing word.

Comment: No problem :) if you can edit your question accordingly would help other users understand better

Comment: But what is a right way to ask? Like 'Do you feel I have a future working here?' Because I like this workplace.

Comment: Waiting until the last week was waiting way to long (at least in larger companies). Were you not talking occasionally about how much you enjoyed working there?

Answer (score 3):

> Should I still express it that if I can have an extension? If yes then how can I put up a request?

It is up to you if you decide to tell your manager that. However, if you really feel like expressing your gratitude and also conveying your interest in continuing your work there you should go for it. Don't hesitate in asking; as I said, trust your instincts and go for it if you want.

When telling her just be honest and express what you are telling us here. Tell her that you found the company and its people a great fit for you, and that you put enthusiasm and interest in the work you did. Then politely her that you are interesting in an extension, as you can keep contributing positive things to the company and their projects.

Keep it honest and simple, no need to provide long explanations on your reasons. Also, I think you have waited enough so you should tell her this **soon**; don't wait until your last day, that way you get at least some days to prepare for job searching in case the answer is negative. Hope this words help you out, and that you stay positive in case you receive a negative answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will ask her in a positive way then. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Good luck, just make sure you do that soon or ASAP, as there is no good in you waiting more time to know that.